# Convert data frame columns to rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe which looks like:

```
time             feature_1   feature_2 feature_3
02.07.2019 00:00  0.1          0.1        0.7
02.07.2019 00:15  0.2          0.4        0.6
02.07.2019 00:30  0.3          0.5        0.7
```

I want to convert it to

```
time              feature    value
02.07.2019 00:00  feature_1   0.1      
02.07.2019 00:00  feature_2   0.1   
02.07.2019 00:00  feature_3   0.7
```

....

I tried df.melt command but not given any results

Comment: `I tried df.melt command but not given any results` and how did you try? `df.melt(id_vars='time')` should do

Comment: dataFrame.melt(id_vars =["time"],
              var_name ="feature", 
              value_name= 'value')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find the code below:

```
import pandas
pd.melt(df,id_vars=['time'],value_vars=['feature_1','feature_2','feature_3']).sort_values('time')
```

Comment: This works, but he time order is completly messed up, is there a way to retain the order

Comment: Use .sort_values('time') this would help in retaining the order.

Comment: add that also in your answer